# Primeng modal box fullscreen

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm currently modifying this component
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/components/dialog/dialog.ts
I want this modalbox to cover the entire screen when it is visible, how can I modify this component? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The width, minWidth, height, and minHeight parameters of the Dialog component should be able to take values of `100%`.